# CSS: Element in flexbox container won't appear unless it or the container are assigned a specific height

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a vertical line inside a flexbox container div, and am finding that unless I give either the line or the container a specific height (like 100px instead of a percentage), the line won't show. Examination with devtools shows that the line has 0 height, even though the container has a non-zero height. I'm guessing that maybe the rendering engine somehow doesn't know about the container's height at the time it's rendering the line? I'd like to find a way to make this work with percentages in order to make the container and line responsive.

jsfiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/jjorsett/d0852yhx/25/][1] Set .line's height units to px and it will show up.

css and html:

```
<div class="container">
  <img class="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x250"/>
  <div class="line">
  </div>
</div>

.container {
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  height: auto;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.line {
    border-left: .25em solid #f60;
    height: 50%;
}
.image {
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 25%;
}
  


  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/jjorsett/d0852yhx/25/
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `align-items: center;` from your container and `height: 50%` from your child and see the magic.

```css
.container {
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  height: auto;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.line {
    border-left: .25em solid #f60;
}
.image {
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x250"/>
  <div class="line">
  </div>
</div>
```

When you align your item in the center it will automatically shrink your child container according to the children of your child div.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the problem is that I'm trying to get the line to span just a part of the container height and not the full height. Also, the align-items is there because in the real code I'm using multiple images of differing sizes and I need them centered vertically. I'm beginning to think I may have to resort to javascript to pull this off.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of anyone else coming across this, I got the behavior I wanted by using javascript as follows (fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/jjorsett/d0852yhx/62/)

```
<div class="container">
  <img class="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x250"/>
  <div id="line">
  </div>
</div>

.container {
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  
  height: auto;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

#line {
    border-left: .25em solid #f60;
    height: 50%;
}
.image {
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 25%;
}


window.onresize = adjustLineSize;
window.onload = adjustLineSize;

function adjustLineSize() {
     var line = document.getElementById("line");
     var desiredLineHeight = line.parentElement.clientHeight/2;
     line.style.height= desiredLineHeight + "px";
}
```